# tensorflow is giving InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape= (227, 227, 3), batch_size=batch_size))
model.add(Conv2D(96,(11, 11),strides=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(256,(5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(384,(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
lr_schedule = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=1e-2,verbose=True)
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
    metrics=['accuracy']    
)
model.fit(train_ds, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=35, callbacks=lr_schedule)
```

Here is some of the error

```
Epoch 1/35
118/119 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 15.6008 - accuracy: 0.4002
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14144/856521488.py in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(train_ds, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=35, callbacks=lr_schedule)

      grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list, grad_loss)
Node: 'gradient_tape/sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/mul'
required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node gradient_tape/sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/mul}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2817]
```

I have tried multiple solutions but nothing is working. Actually I am not understanding what is the error because it seems to me that is nothing wrong with the losses.
And, Actually I am trying to replicate alexnet so if you have any comment about that please tell me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many target class labels do you have, and what are they? It could be that you're target variable has possible values [1,2,3,4] but your model is expecting something between [0,1,2,3]?

Comment: No it  was [0, 1, 2, 3], it was something with the shape, but I solved it after many hours